# In Codeship Basic is redis memory flushed after/before each build?

Tags: redis, codeship

I am using redis-based cache in my application. I am running my integration tests on Codeship Basic and measuring the code coverage. I often see that the code coverage is different for two subsequent builds that use redis cache.

My hypothesis is that redis memory is shared between builds. Is this true?

I am using the default redis at port `6379`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Redis is utilizing the `$HOME/cache` directory within the build, then information would persist between builds. This seems unlikely as it would require a conscious configuration to make use of this directory.

You can read our [dependency cache documentation](https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/builds-and-configuration/dependency-cache/) to learn more.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not using `$HOME/cache` so that pretty much excludes my redis hypothesis.